# How to verify data in table using FitNesse/SLIM?

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am currently having some doubt in verifying the data in grib control. Given a table with ColumnA and ColumnB, lets assume there are 2 rows of records are generated after some search query is applied.

My objective is to ensure the data in ColumnB showing my expectation output, lets assume 'data1' should be shown under ColumnB. May I know how can I verify the data in ColumnB using FitNesse/SLIM?

I have go through the documentation in FitNesse, but it only focus on static data, and it doesn't go through those data generate from database. Do I need to have a database connection in my test program in order to test on the dynamic data?

FYI, I am using JAVA in the development.

THanks @!

Answer (score 2):

Look at [DbFit](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/). It may do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do we have any other options beside this? Because I found out that it could be complicated to tester as they need to learn SQL in their work. Is it possible to hide the internal details like which data from which table because they don't really care about the technical thing so that they can focus on the business functionality?

Comment: You can write a fixture to query the database - here's an example: http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/35009/0/page/4

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your suggestion, your approach is very close to my requirement. But it isn't what I want because I was using SLIM. And also I only want to check on the particular column whether the 'data1' (not 'data2') is shown correctly.

Comment: You can write a similar fixture for SLIM http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.QueryTable to query the database - you can put only the columns you want to test in the query result.